How to deploy laravel project on lightsail container?
I am working aws lightsail container and docker.
I am going to deploy laravel project on lightsail container.
I build docker images (web server, database, project) on linux vps
Web server is ngnix image from docker hub.
Database is mysql image from docker hub.
Project image is built image with dockerfile and php image(fpm)
I built all image successfully.
Next i pushed image on lightsail images.
When i deploy project on lightsail container, all image deployed successfully.
but when i access public domain, i cannt see home page, it display ngnix page.
I want correct solution.
Thanks
I want correct solution and guide.
this is my docker file
FROM php:8.2-fpm-bookworm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install base dependencies and lsb-release
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    wget \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    ca-certificates \
    mariadb-client \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    nano \
    lsb-release \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add MySQL APT repository and GPG key (updated with gpg)
RUN wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.33-1_all.deb -O mysql-apt-config.deb \
    && dpkg -i mysql-apt-config.deb \
    && curl -fsSL https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022 | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mysql.asc \
    && apt-get update

# Install PHP extensions
ADD --chmod=0755 https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN install-php-extensions gd pdo_mysql mysqli mbstring zip exif pcntl

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Create the nginx group and user if they don't already exist
RUN if ! getent group nginx; then groupadd -f -g 1000 nginx; fi \
    && if ! id -u nginx > /dev/null 2>&1; then useradd -u 101 -g nginx -ms /bin/bash nginx; fi

# Copy application files and adjust permissions
COPY ./ /var/www
RUN chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www

# Switch to nginx user for running the application
USER nginx

# Expose port 9000 and run php-fpm
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]


this is my docker-compose.yml file

version: '3'
services:

  # PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:8.2-fpm-bookworm
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  # NGINX Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  # MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: oSFrJiZ1y67nbA41L0pdzOtA5R 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: oSFrJiZ1y67nbA41L0pdzOtA5R
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

# Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

# Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local

this is ngnix config file
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}


